# React Updating Form Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import React from "react"

export default function Form() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(
        {firstName: ""}
    )
    
    console.log(formData.comments)
    
    function handleChange(event) {
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <form>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="firstName"
                value={formData.firstName}
            />
        </form>
    )
}
```

I'm trying to understand a few aspects of that that I'm not 100% on, and would appreciate if anyone could advise.

My understanding of the order of operations is as such:

1. The user types text into the input
2. onChange runs and triggers the handleChange callback
3. The handle change callback runs. This triggers the setter function which changes the state.
4. The form component is re-rendered due to the setter function being run.

I believe this is right, but it leads to a bit of confusion for me:

1. How is the `console.log(formData.comments)` being run each time a change is made? Does this happen when the form component is re-rendered? And if so, why doesn't `const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({firstName: ""});` also reset each time?
2. When my handleChange function runs, it triggers the callback which returns an identical object, except that we reassign one property, which is: `[event.target.name] : event.target.value`. If event.target.name and event.target.value are coming from what I pass to the input component, and `value={formData.firstName}`, how does my state ever update? Since I type a new character in the field, but the state isn't updated, and therefore value isn't updated, which means the old value should still be used.
3. Where can I view more information about event which is passed to my handler function?

Thanks to anyone who can help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The console statement runs because of the re-rendering of the component . Since formData is a state and uses useState api , it is not meant to re-initialize . Thats how react works since it compares the DOM to render new changes .
2. The setFormData is called and although it still contains the previous value since you are hardcoding the input value which is same as before but since the set method api of the useState is called the component is bound to re-render . Again this is how react works
3. You can always console log the event you passed inside the handler

Comment: Hi Tarmah, thank you for your answer.

1 and 3 make perfect sense and answer my quesstions.

I'm still a bit confused about 2. If setFormData is called on the previous value when the component re-renders should it not display the old data?

Comment: So whenever you call the setter method of the useState api , no matter even if the value is same as the old one , the component will still re-render and a new object with the same values will be set . Although the values will be the same but a new object will be set . In other words A new instance of an object with same values will be set .